# Tomcat "connection interrupted" with ssl

Tags: ssl, tomcat, java

I can access Tomcat on port 8080, but not on 8443. When I try o get there, this is the error I get in Firefox:

> The connection was interrupted The connection to the.fqdn.com:8443 was
>   interrupted while the page was loading.

This is my connector:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLS" 
    keystoreFile="C:\temp\keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit"/>
```

I have the CA key in the jre's cacerts file.

The server cert was generated using EJBCA and should be signed properly. Any suggestions on what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You have client authentication set to optional/wanted. AFAIK, most browsers don't support this mode.

Either disable it or set it enabled if your really require it

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient for note about optional SSL client cert mode